# Counting null dates in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, null

I have a question with null dates in Oracle

I've got a table like this:

```
ID   DATE
1     '02/08/2015'
1     NULL
1    '02/06/2014'
2    NULL
2    '06/02/2013'
```

This is just an example of the real table. Now what I need is something like this:

```
ID   DAY_INAC
1    1
2    1
```

I mean, I need to count only the null values present in the DATE column.

But when I execute my query

```
Select id, count(date)
from table
where date is null
group by Id
having count(date)>0
```

As a result I'm getting nothing. What do I need to with the date value in order to generate the corresponding counting.

Regards

Comment: use `count(*) ` if you want to count rows. use `count(somecol)` only if you need to count the rows where said column is not null

Comment: @MT0: It must be a mistake. The question is pretty clear that it's Oracle. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 4):

Because your query is already filtering by `date is null`, you just need to use `count(*)`

```
Select id, count(*)
from table
where date is null
group by Id
having count(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT` does not count `NULL` values. You can use `CASE` to change them:

```
Select id, count(CASE WHEN date IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS DAY_INAC
from table
where date is null
group by Id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407434)**</kbd>

Please do not name column as datatypes. Otherwise you may need to quote them.

Comment: you don't need `where date is null` :) It is useful only if you have a function based index on the case expression and rewrite that as `CASE WHEN date IS NULL THEN 1 END = 1`

Comment: @FlorinGhita I need. Please check [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407437). OP has also`having count(date)>0`

Comment: mmm... yes you are right. If you omit the `where` you'll got those with zero null dates.

Answer (score 1):

A more condensed query:

```
Select id, count(nvl2(date_column,null, sysdate)) as cnt
from table
group by Id;
```

Comment: ouch, didn't notice that :)

Comment: Why would it have to work with `SQL-SERVER`? The question specifically states Oracle in the text.

Comment: @MT0 At the beginning it has SQL-Server tag. Check edit history

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` will not count `NULL` values - instead get it to count a literal value (i.e. `1`) for those rows that are `NULL`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2d39/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, "DATE" ) AS
          SELECT 1, DATE '2015-08-02' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, DATE '2014-06-02' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, DATE '2013-02-06' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  id,
        COUNT(1)
FROM    table_name
WHERE   "DATE" IS NULL
GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2d39/2/0)**:

```
| ID | COUNT(1) |
|----|----------|
|  1 |        1 |
|  2 |        1 |
```